# Editar Texto en html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Necesito saber si hay alguna forma de habilitar una etiqueta de texto para poder ser editada  en html con jquery

por ejemplo tengo una etiqueta p que se muestra como texto plano en html pero quiero que al presionar un boton este se habilite como si fuera un textarea y se pueda editar. al terminar vuelva a ser un elemento p o de texto plano en html.

Gracias.

Comment: todas las etiquetas pueden ser editables con jquery, creo que tu pregunta es muy vaga, deberias ver el manual [enlace]https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: mi problema no es con jquery desde js sino desde el mismo html por ejemplo preciono un boton y en vez de texto plano pasa a ser texto editable en el html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con el atributo contenteditable te puede salir eso:

Fuente[: developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content)

```js
$(function(){
  $('#btnEditable').on('click', function(){
    var esEditable = $('#idTexto').attr('contenteditable');
    if(esEditable){
      $('#idTexto').attr('contenteditable', false);
      $('#btnEditable').html('Hacerlo Editable');
    }else{
      $('#idTexto').attr('contenteditable', true);
      $('#btnEditable').html('dejar der editar');
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="idTexto">Este contenido se volverá editable</div>
<button id="btnEditable">Hacerlo Editable</button>
```

Comment: Tremendo y Gracias.

Comment: Márcala como correcta si te ayudo.

Answer (score 0):

Por ejemplo un texto dentro de las etiquetas **p**

```
<p>Ejemplo</p>
```

Lo puedes modificar con **jQuery** así:

```
$('p').html('Edición');
```

Comment: mi problema no es con jquery desde js sino desde el mismo html por ejemplo preciono un boton y en vez de texto plano pasa a ser texto editable en el html

Comment: . @ArmandoMariscal No todas las preguntas se pueden o se deben contestar. Ahórrate un poco de frustración y evita responder a preguntas que  son inciertas o requieren demasiada orientación para que puedas contestarla completamente. Tienes suficiente reputación para haber dejado esto como un comentario en lugar de como una respuesta. Lee [answer] para más información.

Answer (score 0):

Casi cualquier etiqueta se puede modificar con jQuery.

aqui el html

```
//el input esta solo lectura actualmente 
    <input  size="30" id="mi_input" type="text" value="Descripcion" readonly>
//boton con su id
    <button type='submit'id='id_boton' class='btn btn-warning '>Boton Editar</button>
```

aqui el js

```
$("#id_boton").click(function(){
    //remueves el atributo de solo leer
  $('#mi_input').removeAttr('readonly');

}
```

espero te sirva bro... ReNiceCode...

Comment: mi problema no es con jquery desde js sino desde el mismo html por ejemplo preciono un boton y en vez de texto plano pasa a ser texto editable en el html

Comment: mira ahi modifique la respuesta, creo que es lo que necesitas...

Comment: ooh buena el readonly lo pruebo y te comento. gracias.

Comment: no me funciono utilizando un input readonly porque se me va todo el texto y el lugar donde tengo ese texto es super pequeño, lo que tengo es una etiqueta small en un td de una tabla.

Comment: @srJJ no me digas maestro, soy amigo. Nadie esta molesto al contrario **se agradece tu gran ayuda en el sitio**, la cual es valiosa!, aquí lo que sucede es que la pregunta del OP se realizo sin agregar el código que realizo o trato, además de aclarar su pregunta, en ocasiones tratamos de ayudar y al final no es lo que en realidad preguntaba el OP. De hecho ahora veo muchas respuestas a la pregunta, lo cual no es malo pero debería preguntar basándose en [ask].

Comment: @Jorgesys llevo algo de tiempo aqui y se quien es quien y se que tu reputacion no te las has ganado editando comentario, y digo Maestro como un formalismo a alguien que sabe muchisimo, es algo asi como "respetar a los mayores" de todas formas muchas gracias por todo.

Comment: MaxFuentes entonces siendo asi, cabe mencionar que como dijo el Maestro @Jorgesys debes poner tu codigo para mirar que es lo que necesitas y con eso basarnos y darte una respuesta mas clara

Answer (score 0):

Lo que estás buscando es el atributo `contenteditable` que tienen algunos elementos HTML para que el usuario pueda editar su contenido interno.

¿Has visto editores de ciertos sitios que permiten dan formato al texto cuando estás escribiendo? Algunos de ellos utilizan dicha propiedad. Si no logras ubicarlos, la nueva versión de Reddit tiene uno de ellos cuando quieres agregar un nuevo comentario, por decir un ejemplo.

Su uso es muy sencillo, y de acuerdo a la [documentación de Mozilla Developers Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Atributos_Globales/contenteditable) siempre debes especificar un valor a dicho atributo. Te explico:

Esta etiqueta te permitirá insertar contenido dentro de la misma.

```
<p contenteditable="true"></p>
```

Esta etiqueta se mostrará como un párrafo en tu documento.

```
<p contenteditable="false"></p>
```

Pero nunca hagas esto:

```
<p contenteditable=""></p>
<p contenteditable></p>
```

Para la integración con Javascript y jQuery, se me ocurre algo rápido como lo siguiente:

```
let bandera = true; // La bandera cambia su valor entre verdadero y falso cada vez que el usuario hace clic sobre el botón
let funcion = function(evento){
  evento.preventDefault(); // Cuando invocamos esta función, le decimos al navegador que no ejecute la acción por defecto de dicho botón y en su lugar proceda con las instrucciones que le damos aquí abajo
  jQuery('p').attr('contenteditable', bandera);
  bandera = !bandera; // Simplemente intercambiamos su valor anterior
}
jQuery(document).on('click', 'button', funcion);
```

Si necesitas hacer algo más complejo, considera utilizar algunas librerías ya existentes como [Trumbowyg](https://alex-d.github.io/Trumbowyg/).

Comment: Muchas Gracias.